# cannot execute php on monkey server

Tags: php, server, monkey

i am running linux Mint Mate 19.3 32 bits on my desktop

I installed monkey server 1.6.9  and php7.2-fpm to run php-based web sites made by my students.

Unfortunaty the code  in index.php via 127.0.0.1:2001

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

is not executed and the source is displayed instead.

i checked :

- php7.2-fpm is running and does not show any error in /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log
- running monkey does not show any error, fastcgi plugin is loaded. (proper fastcgi entry in plugins.load)
- on conf/sites/default :

```
[HANDLERS]
    # FastCGI
    # =======
    Match /.*\.php fastcgi
```

- on  conf/plugins/fastcgi   (i checked the path of the sock)

```
[FASTCGI_SERVER]
        ServerName php7.2-fpm1
        ServerPath /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
        MaxConnections 5

[FASTCGI_LOCATION]
        LocationName php7.2_location
        ServerNames php7.2-fpm1
        KeepAlive On
        Match /*.php
```

I don't know what to do .
Any help will be welcomed.

Tran